# What is the point of Measure() if onMeasure() does all the actual measuring?

Tags: android

I do not understand when the Measure() method should be used, if onMeasure() is what does the measuring, and measure doesn't even need to be called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure actually calls onMeasure:

> The actual measurement work of a view is performed in onMeasure(int, int), called by this method. Therefore, only onMeasure(int, int) can and must be overridden by subclasses.

Behind the scenes, Measure essentially caches the current value, so onMeasure is only called when the element is resized.  This way, you don't need to implement logic in onMeasure to determine if the layout has changed.

Comment: So, what you're saying is onMeasure will only be called again, if you have a/another Measure() with different constraints on the width and height?

Comment: @user2913567 It may have changed in recent versions, but IIRC it should not be called again (and you can get the values directly with getMeasuredHeight and getMeasuredWidth)

Answer (score 0):

One example that I have used is: you want to know the size of something before it's actually drawn.  Prior to calling `Measure()`, the system does not know the actual physical size of how something will be drawn to the screen.  By calling `Measure()`, you can find out how large something is going to be, if other logic depends on it.